# What was an Amiga "X-Drive"?

Tags: amiga

In computer magazine personal ads from the 1990s, I notice multiple mentions of Amigas "with X-Drive". Searching online, I find no mention of this. (Possibly this is because search engines of late seem to ignore quotes and thus make almost any query's results meaningless.)

What exactly was the Amiga "X-Drive"? Some kind of hard drive interface?

Comment: This Swedish computer magazine from 1993 has multiple personal ads selling Amigas with "x-drive": https://archive.org/details/Datormagazin1993_201809/Datormagazin_1993_nr08/page/n67/mode/2up?q=%22x+drive%22  I too have to think it's shorthand for "external drive."

Comment: Good find Jim..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your question could be improved with some example screenshots of adverts you've seen, otherwise it could really be anything.

I think it's most likely that in the pay-per-word cramped space of a magazine trading advert, the phrase "with X-Drive" means the item comes with an **ex**ternal (or **ex**tra) floppy drive, which was a common Amiga expansion for all models for productivity use.

[image]
[Image CC BY SA, author: Multicherry](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Cumana_CAX_354_Disk_Drive_for_Amiga_(front_and_top).jpg)

Similarly "with 2x Drive" could mean it comes with 'two additional drives' (and very unlikely but still possible that it would come with a 2X speed CD-ROM drive).

It's also possible you were seeing adverts for Amigas with the animation package X-DVE (sometimes called X Drive), which was given away with Amiga Format issue 88.

Comment: Thanks for the checkmark but it's possible there is a something like a HDD expansion by that name, so don't be too hasty. :)